# ModRewrite and the url

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url

I have something like that :

.htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^news/?(\d+)/?$ /?pg=news&id=$1 [NC]
```

header.php :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../theme/style.css" media="all" >
```

The problem is the following : when i go to **www.domain.com/news/241** i get the error "404 Not Found" of the **style.css** file.

I replaced the `../theme/style.css` with `<?=HOST;?>/theme/style.css` where `HOST` is the domain name. How to do it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use absolute paths for all your links / assets (js, css, images, etc.):

```
/theme/style.css
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a rewrite rule in front of you rewrite rule that excludes your content directories:

```
RewriteRule ^(images¦javascript¦theme) - [L]
```

The above rule tells `mod_rewrite` to exclude matching directories